# Compare Multiple Differences in Java Strings

Tags: java

I have a string template that looks something like this:

```
This position is reserved for <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>. Start date is <XXXXXXXX>
```

Filled out, this might look like this (fixed width is preserved):

```
This position is reserved for <JOHN SMITH                 >. Start date is <20150228>
```

How can I extract multiple differences in a single String? I don't want to use an entire templating engine for one task if I can avoid it.

Comment: What output expected?

Comment: The output expected is shown.

Comment: Why don't use `substring()` then? For you example s.substring(31, 58) will return `JOHN SMITH                 ` and so on.

Answer (score 10):

You can try regex like this :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "This position is reserved for <JOHN SMITH                 >. Start date is <20150228>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?<(.*?)>.*<(.*?)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Name : " +m.group(1).trim());
        System.out.println("Date : " +m.group(2).trim());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
Name : JOHN SMITH
Date : 20150228
```

Answer (score 1):

If the template might be modified you could use a format pattern.

```
String expected = "This position is reserved for <JOHN SMITH                 >. Start date is <20150228>";
System.out.println(expected);
// define the output format
String template = "This position is reserved for <%-27s>. Start date is <%s>";
String name = "JOHN SMITH";
String startDate = "20150228";
// output the values using the defined format
System.out.println(String.format(template, name, startDate));
```